# How to make slickgrid headers editable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, slickgrid

How to make any custom formatter to make a header cell editable in Slickgrid

Looking for any custom formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of any plugin to do that at the moment. Probably not too hard to write your own editor for that, though, using existing code as a start.

Edit: I am the owner of the current active SlickGrid repo (https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid)